PyPSA-Eur Error in rule build_renewable_profiles
The problem:
I am getting the following RuleException/Error in rule build_renewable_profiles
when running the
snakemake --cores 'all' resources/networks/elec.nc:
RuleException:
CalledProcessError in file /home/madz/Downloads/new_download/pypsa-eur/rules/build_electricity.smk, line 325:
Command 'set -euo pipefail;  /opt/miniconda3/envs/new_dl/bin/python3.11 /home/madz/Downloads/new_download/pypsa-eur/.snakemake/scripts/tmph18rnyaq.build_renewable_profiles.py' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[Sat Apr  6 15:55:00 2024]
Error in rule build_renewable_profiles:
jobid: 11
input: resources/networks/base.nc, data/bundle/corine/g250_clc06_V18_5.tif, resources/natura.tiff, data/bundle/GEBCO_2014_2D.nc, resources/shipdensity_raster.tif, resources/country_shapes.geojson, resources/offshore_shapes.geojson, resources/regions_offshore.geojson, cutouts/europe-2013-era5.nc
output: resources/profile_offwind-dc.nc
log: logs/build_renewable_profile_offwind-dc.log (check log file(s) for error details)
conda-env: /home/madz/Downloads/new_download/pypsa-eur/.snakemake/conda/33db58cf3c3662ba6e2d07fe382b920e_
Test for PyPSA-Eur finished sucessfully, the snakemake fails with the above error message.
It is performed on a slightly modified config.yaml (solver settings, country selection)

It is performed on cloned master git branch (release 0.10.0 Feb. 19th '24.). 

--
Attempted soluton:
I tried cloning git repo multiple times + downloading the whole datase.
I tried the:
snakemake -call purge
snakemake -call solve_elec_networks
commands alternative, which fails as well with the same error message.
